# Correct Vim package for python development?

Tags: python

I'm trying to setup Vim with Flake8, YouCompleteMe and other python add-ons using Vundle.

What is the correct Vim package (vim/vim-gtk/vim-gtk3/...) to install on Linux? I noticed after `apt install vim-gtk`, python3 is enabled but not python when I run `vim --version`.

Remark: I have no need for a GUI based editor.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, "python" means Python 2. Note that this is just for Vim's scripting interface (see `:h +python`). You can edit Python files without any of this.

On Debian, the package `vim-gtk3` works fine, `vim-gtk` is an alias for `vim-gtk3` and `vim-athena` works as well. I have no need for a GUI version, either but the non-GUI packages often offer limited functionality. If space is not a concern, install any of these. There is no single "correct" version.